# Why does cout << "" work but wcout << "" not?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

Why `std::wcout << L"ي" << std::endl;` doesn't print actual character?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"));
    std::cout << "ي" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"ي" << std::endl;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5252259fa9e9838a)**
I define a suitable locale, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @SamOlesen The solution looks exactly the same...

Answer (score 2):

The error is mixing `std::cout` and `std::wcout`:

> ### 27.4 Standard iostream objects `[iostream.objects]`
>
> #### 27.4.1 Overview `[iostream.objects.overview]`
>
> 3 Mixing operations on corresponding wide- and narrow-character streams follows the same semantics as
>   mixing such operations on FILEs, as specified in Amendment 1 of the ISO C standard.

> #### 7.21.2 Streams
>
> 4 Each stream has an orientation. After a stream is associated with an external file, but
>   before any operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation. Once a wide
>   character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the
>   stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has
>   been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream.
>   Only a call to the freopen function or the fwide function can otherwise alter the
>   orientation of a stream. (A successful call to freopen removes any orientation.)267)
>   5 **Byte input/output functions shall not be applied to a wide-oriented stream and wide
>   character input/output functions shall not be applied to a byte-oriented stream.** [...]

See here for a better demonstration highlighting what goes wrong and what does not:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c3a34c0c4523016